# Key-Value vs Wide-Column DB

Tags: database, key-value, wide-column-store, nosql

I want to know what is the difference between a persistent key-value DB and a wide-column DB. I understand in both DBs you retrieve a single value by a key, so what is the difference between the types of the values?

Thanks!